# Use inputs multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `input` fields `type:number` which all are called separately when pushed on a button. 
For instance, I click on `button1` then `dialog1` appears and so on..
What I want to do in code behind (`jQuery`) is to get the value from the number input and place it in `<div class="total-price"></div>`

```
<div id="dialog1">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="number" class="col-md-4 amount" id="amount" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
    <div class="total-price">Total:</div>
</div>

<div id="dialog2">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="number" class="col-md-4 amount" id="amount" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
    <div class="total-price">Total:</div>
</div>

<div id="dialog3">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="number" class="col-md-4 amount" id="amount" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
    <div class="total-price">Total:</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $(".amount").change(function(){
    price = 9.99;
    amount = $(".amount").val()
    total = price * amount;
    $(".total-price").html("Totaal: &euro; " + total);
  });
```

This works fine, but it changes ALL the `.total-price` divs... I could work with `id` but I'm not here for `id="amount1"`, `id="amount2`", `id="amount3"`

That's so messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) and also change `$('.amount').val()` to `$(this).val()` (to get the value of input being referred to)

```
  $(".amount").change(function(){
    price = 9.99;
    amount = $(this).val()
    total = price * amount;
    $(this).siblings(".total-price").html("Totaal: &euro; " + total);
  });
```

```js
$(".amount").change(function(){
    price = 9.99;
    amount = $(this).val()
    total = price * amount;
    $(this).siblings(".total-price").html("Totaal: &euro; " + total);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog1">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="number" class="col-md-4 amount" id="amount" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
    <div class="total-price">Total:</div>
</div>

<div id="dialog2">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="number" class="col-md-4 amount" id="amount" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
    <div class="total-price">Total:</div>
</div>

<div id="dialog3">
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="number" class="col-md-4 amount" id="amount" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
    <div class="total-price">Total:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. All answers were good, but I picked this as solution as you've added a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

change the lines

```
amount = $(".amount").val()
$(".total-price").html("Totaal: &euro; " + total);
```

to

```
amount = $(this).val(); 
$(this).parent().find(".total-price").html("Totaal: &euro; " + total);
```

Comment: This in an incomplete solution. There is a mistake on #3 (`amount=..`)of OP's code as well. Please update

Answer (score 1):

use `.next()` in jquery

```
$(this).val(); //to get current input 
$(this).next().html("Totaal: &euro; " + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the input and the div are in the same level, you can use `siblings()` from jQuery.

```
$(".amount").change(function() {
    price = 9.99;
    amount = $(this).val(); //This will get the value from the current input
    total = price * amount;
    $(this).siblings(".total-price").html("Total: &euro;"+total);
});
```

You need to use `this` when you are inside an element to refer that element.